svrl:failed-assert location attribute normalize element names
Just made a validation of my xml file with schxslt compiled xsl file with SaxonCS. In the output of svrl report, failed location looks like this.
<svrl:failed-assert location="/Q{http://www.edefter.gov.tr}defter[1]/Q{http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance}xbrl[1]/Q{http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/cor/2006-10-25}accountingEntries[1]/Q{http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/cor/2006-10-25}entryHeader[298]"
                       test="some-test">
      <svrl:text>some-message</svrl:text>
   </svrl:failed-assert>

Is there any possible way to retrieve xml elements with namespaces
<svrl:failed-assert location="/edefter:defter[1]/xbrli:xbrl[1]/gl-cor:accountingEntries[1]/gl-cor:entryHeader[298]"
                       test="some-test">
      <svrl:text>some-message</svrl:text>
   </svrl:failed-assert>

like this.
I tried to find a way to supply namespaces or import schemas but could not found a way.
Edit:
here is the namespaces of the svrl file before compile
<xsl:transform version="2.0"
           xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/TransformAlias"
           xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
           xmlns:error="https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1495494#error"
           xmlns:schxslt="https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1495494"
           xmlns:schxslt-api="https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1495494#api"
           xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

and here is the the namespaces of the compiled svrl report
<svrl:schematron-output xmlns:defterek="http://www.edefter.gov.tr/ek"
                        xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
                        xmlns:edefter="http://www.edefter.gov.tr"
                        xmlns:error="https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1495494#error"
                        xmlns:gl-bus="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/bus/2006-10-25"
                        xmlns:gl-cor="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/cor/2006-10-25"
                        xmlns:gl-muc="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/muc/2006-10-25"
                        xmlns:gl-plt="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/plt/2010-04-16"
                        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
                        xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
                        xmlns:schxslt="https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1495494"
                        xmlns:schxslt-api="https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1495494#api"
                        xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl"
                        xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#"
                        xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"
                        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        title="Yevmiye defteri dokumanlarını kontrol etmek için gerekli olan schematron kuralları">


 <svrl:ns-prefix-in-attribute-values prefix="gl-plt" uri="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/plt/2010-04-16"/>
   <svrl:ns-prefix-in-attribute-values prefix="gl-cor" uri="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/cor/2006-10-25"/>
   <svrl:ns-prefix-in-attribute-values prefix="gl-bus" uri="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/bus/2006-10-25"/>
   <svrl:ns-prefix-in-attribute-values prefix="gl-muc" uri="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/muc/2006-10-25"/>
   <svrl:ns-prefix-in-attribute-values prefix="xbrli" uri="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"/>
   <svrl:ns-prefix-in-attribute-values prefix="ds" uri="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
   <svrl:ns-prefix-in-attribute-values prefix="xades" uri="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#"/>
   <svrl:ns-prefix-in-attribute-values prefix="edefter" uri="http://www.edefter.gov.tr"/>
   <svrl:ns-prefix-in-attribute-values prefix="defterek" uri="http://www.edefter.gov.tr/ek"/>


Namespace prefixes like edefter or xbrli only make sense if the SVRL report declares them. Consider to show a minimal but complete SVRL where we see all namespace declarations.

Hi @MartinHonnen. Sorry for misinformation. I have edited the question with contents of compile-for-svrl.xsl and svrl report.

I think Schxslt by default in some versions uses the XPath fn:path function to output location information, it might be possible to provide your own function, depending on the exact Schxslt version. Which Schxslt version do you use? As an alternative you would need to tokenize the given location and break tokens up to get a QName and then use e.g. XPath https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-prefix-from-QName. All doable with pure XPath or XPath in XSLT but requires some coding.

I am using the code sample from one of your repo. I guess it is v1.9.5. I am sending the GitHub link.
https://github.com/martin-honnen/SchematronSchxsltSaxonCSValidator

In your Schematron you can provide your own schxslt:location function e.g.
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:schxslt="https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1495494" queryBinding="xslt3">
    <xsl:function name="schxslt:location" as="xs:string">
      <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
      <xsl:sequence
        select="string-join($node/ancestor-or-self::*!node-name(), '/')"/>
    </xsl:function>

That example is just to show you how to set up your own function, the function body is not an implementation of the path with positional predicates you want to generate but just generates a path with node-names. But you can adapt that function to your needs, the original Schxslt implementation that however tries to mimic the path function result is at https://github.com/schxslt/schxslt/blob/main/core/src/main/resources/xslt/2.0/compile/compile-2.0.xsl#L185. In that code instead of the Q{ namespace-uri and local name concatenation you seem to want to simply output the node-name() of a an element node plus the positional predicate.
I have now tried to spell that out as
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:schxslt="https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1495494" queryBinding="xslt3">
    
    <xsl:function name="schxslt:location" as="xs:string">
      <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="segments" as="xs:string*">
            <xsl:for-each select="($node/ancestor-or-self::node())">
              <xsl:variable name="position">
                <xsl:number level="single"/>
              </xsl:variable>
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test=". instance of element()">
                  <xsl:value-of select="concat(node-name(), '[', $position, ']')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". instance of attribute()">
                  <xsl:value-of select="concat('@', node-name())"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". instance of processing-instruction()">
                  <xsl:value-of select="concat('processing-instruction(&quot;', name(.), '&quot;)[', $position, ']')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". instance of comment()">
                  <value-of select="concat('comment()[', $position, ']')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". instance of text()">
                  <xsl:value-of select="concat('text()[', $position, ']')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise/>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:variable>

          <xsl:sequence select="concat('/', string-join($segments, '/'))"/>

    </xsl:function>

I have put an online fiddle that runs SaxonJS at this link.

Thank you for the reply. This function must be in ".sch" file, right ? And when you implement it like this, how can I call in svrl.xsl ? Also,
What would you recommend to debug these files ? I mean, when I have xml and xslt, I can perform step-by-step debugging via Visual Studio. But I couldn't found a way for this.

There is a proposal for XPath 4.0 to include a variant of the fn:path() function that will use namespace prefixes rather than URIs: see https://qt4cg.org/pr/1620/xpath-functions-40/autodiff.html (link may expire)

@CemalÇelik, when you add the function as shown in the example of the answer to your Schematron file (e.g. .sch) file with that namespace and name then Schxslt should do the rest automatically and use it, there is no need to edit/change the the Schxslt XSLT files.

@MartinHonnen, I have made the changes you said. My questions could be sound stupid, sorry for that but this is something I am new to. When doing schematronValidator.Transform, I am receiving an exception like this Errors were reported during JIT compilation of template rule with match="/"
sch namespaces:
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:schxslt="https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1495494" queryBinding="xslt2">

@CemalÇelik, to allow us to tell what has gone wrong we would need to see a minimal but complete sample to reproduce the error. I can't tell from that error what has gone wrong. I have extended the answer with a full function implementation and a link to a working Schematron fiddle (although that works in the browser using SaxonJS and a new Schxslt version but I don't think it makes a difference but hope it helps you find on your own where things might be wrong in your attempt).

@CemalÇelik, I have also updated https://github.com/martin-honnen/SchematronSchxsltSaxonCSValidator, it now contains a sample Schematron with that location function and for that example runs fine with SaxonCS 12.5.

@MartinHonnen Okay, I am stupid :D I have realized that i forgot to take the closing tag of xsl:function. thats why it was crashing on run-time.  Now, it has given the desired output.  Thank y'all for your effort.
